# How do you stop URL Rewrites resetting in CE 1.9?

Tags: url-rewrite

This exact question has already been asked here:

[URL Rewrite resetting "Permanent" redirects](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71895/url-rewrite-resetting-permanent-redirects#new-answer?newreg=c9ee1bb3430e4f038fd2a4bc9194093d)

But it hasn't been answered yet.  This is my first time on this site and I wasn't sure if I should ask a whole new question or 'answer' the other question with the same question.

Basically, I set up URL Rewrites for my some of my categories but they get reset on indexing and (possibly) when I modify categories.

Can somebody please tell me the best solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did for my site:

1. Edit URL rewrite for your new category by setting Re-direct to Permanent

[image]

2. Add New Custom URL Rewrite

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was following someone else's advice which was to delete the original system URL Rewrite.  Your solution of creating a custom Rewrite that works in conjunction with the original system one, works great!